# Link is not working in Wamp server for a Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, cpanel

I have a running Laravel project in my CPanel. Now I have downloaded the project and run into my local server Wamp.

After successfully installing the project in my local server Wamp,project `Home page` is successfully shown but all the others links is not working. It redirect another Wamp server page with configuration details like below image.

[image]

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'homeController@index');
Route::get('/about-us', 'homeController@about_us');
Route::get('/doctor', 'homeController@doctor');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
Voyager::routes();
});
Route::any('{catchall}', function() {
return App::call('App\Http\Controllers\errorController@error');
})->where('catchall', '.*');
```

**vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName senior_citizen_hospital
DocumentRoot "f:/wampp/www/senior_citizen_hospital"
<Directory  "f:/wampp/www/senior_citizen_hospital/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
```

I can't understand where is the problem ?Anybody help please ?

If need any further information please tell me.

Comment: can you share your localhost url.

Comment: @WorldsHero..I have updated my post

Comment: please share you ``web.php`` file

Comment: @ArafatRahman Can you share vhost configuration.

Comment: Please, share your route file and at least one controller.

Comment: @ArafatRahman For Laravel Projects apache configuration generally points to public folder :

DocumentRoot "f:/wampp/www/senior_citizen_hospital/public/"

Comment: @ImranKhan....bro I have change the root... but still not change